# Adapters and recycled views with dynamic number of elements in them

Tags: android

So I have a `ListView` in which each list item kind of looks like
[image: Holder my ViewHolder]

Its pretty easy to insert those checkboxes. I do them so

```
public class QuestionableActivity extends Activity {
    private QuestionableListAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.questionable_activity);

        if(mAdapter == null){
            mAdapter = new QuestionableListAdapter();
        }

        ListView questionListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.questionable_listview);
        questionListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public static class QuestionableListItemFragment extends Fragment {
        public QuestionableListItemFragment() {}
    }

    private class QuestionableListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private ArrayList<QuestionableListItemFragment> mList;
        private QuestionableListAdapter() {
            mList = new ArrayList<QuestionableListItemFragment>();
            for (int i = 0; i <  10; i+=1){
                mList.add(new QuestionableListItemFragment());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 10;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return mList.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            if(view == null){
                view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.question_fragment, null);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                LinearLayout qOption = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.question_option_fragment, viewGroup, false);
                ((LinearLayout) view).addView(qOption);
            }
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

I do understand the concept that in a listview, views are recylced. Hence, in my `adapter`,

1. `if(view == null)` - a new view is being created for the first time, so inflate my `list item fragment xml`
2. `else` - being reused, so simply update the view elements in the fragment

This much, I get. But now, does this mean that when I have to create/update a new fragment, I have to remove all the dynamically created elements and then recreate them again, as they may/may not be relevant to the particular fragment? If I don't do this, for every fragment that comes into view, this happens

[image: Woe becomes me!]

The checkboxes will be added **each** time. This makes perfect sense, but what then is the best way to do such things?

Answer (score 0):

You have added views four times in each loop, why not write the 4 views in your R.layout.question_option_fragment xml

Comment: Well you see,that's just for illustration purposes. The actual count will be backed by a db

Comment: You can write the 4 views in xml, then you can set the 4 views property such as visibility, background... You can inflate them only one time

Comment: There are no `4` views, there are `n` views which already have backing XMLs. I just need to know the right pattern for dynamically inserting them and updating them when the view is recycled